# NumPy's ndarrays vs Python's lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm a beginner to Python and I've recently learned about NumPy and its famous *ndarrays*. At first, after reading many people praising them (some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists/994545), [here](https://www.studytonight.com/post/numpy-array-over-python-list), [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hitchhiker-guide-to-python-numpy-arrays-9358de570121)), I thought:

"Well, if NumPy's arrays are so much better, and assuming I don't really care about having heterogeneous data types on the same list/array, why should I ever use Python's list?"

However, after a deeper research, I've found that using *ndarrays* also have negative sides (some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232406/why-is-a-for-over-a-python-list-faster-than-over-a-numpy-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202341/why-is-numpy-ndarray-much-slower-than-lists-for-simple-loops)). I've understood the basic pros and cons of using each of these data structures, but this all still seems very confusing to me. So, my question is: **as a beginner in Python, when should I use NumPy's arrays and when should I use Python's lists? How can I, given a situation, evaluate which option is the best?**

Some may be inclined to consider this post a duplicate - and there are indeed many "ndarrays vs lists" topics already. However, I've searched for a while and I didn't find a satisfying answer for my question. There are many people talking about the benefits of *ndarrays* and lists, but it's still not clear, specially for beginners like me, how to choose between them. Should I use NumPy arrays in my day-to-day coding and save lists for special situations? Or should I do the opposite? Thank you!

**Note:** since it might be relevant for the answers, I intend to use Python mostly for Machine Learning.

Comment: Lists are basic python structures, that get used in many roles.  `numpy` is primarily a numeric tool - matrices, higher dimensional arrays.  It's been extended to time series with `pandas`, and machine learning with `sklearn` and `tensorflow/keras`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python lists are more bulky. They're basically arrays of pointers, which take up far more memory than numpy's `ndarrays`. As a result, for mathematical operations involving matrices and complex calculations, `ndarrays` are the better option. Because of this, most mathematical operations have been optimized for numpy and there are more mathematically useful functions for `ndarrays`.

Python lists are much more flexible, though. They can hold heterogeneous, arbitrary data, and appending/removing is very efficient. If you'd like to add and remove many different objects, Python lists are the way to go.

For the purpose of machine learning, `ndarrays` are definitely your best bet. Tensorflow and keras, the two most popular machine learning libraries, are more suited to numpy's memory-efficient arrays because they deal with large amounts of homogeneous data.